# Show that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ any subspace M of $X=(\mathbb{R}^n,\Vert \cdot \Vert_2)$, M is closed in $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I know that every finite-dimensional normed linear space is closed. Moreover $X$ is Banach. Since M is a subspace of $X$ does this conclude that it is closed? I doubt so, because it is not stated that M is finite-dimensional or infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Since $\Bbb R^n$ is finite-dimensional, any subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ is finite-dimensional too.

Comment: I guess that completes the idea. Because every finite-dimensional subspace of a Banach space is closed. Thank you

Comment: You do not need to use theory of Banach spaces, just take an orthonormal basis of $M$ and study the convergence of a Cauchy sequence in $M$.